# why is my regular expression not validating a valid expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am at a lost as to why this will not.

here is my regular expression:

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[\\\+\=\.\[\]_£|`¬':;~{}<>()#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,20}$
```

here is some code to simply test it:

```
var str1 = "AAbb123.";
var str2 = "ell";
var re = new RegExp("^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[\\\+\=\.\[\]_£|\`¬':\;\~{}<>()#?!\@$\%^&*-]).{8,20}$"); 
if(str1.match(re)){
   alert("matched")
   }
       else {
       alert("doesnt match")
       }
```

the regular expression has been validated in 2 regular expression web sites (regexpal.com & http://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html). both say str1 is valid for this expression but yet when included in my code it will not work.

below is another place I am trying to get the code working. and it keeps printing: requirements not met.

```
var uname = document.getElementById("pword1").value;
var re = new RegExp ("^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[\\\+\=\.\[\]_£|\`¬':\;\~{}<>()#?!\@$\%^&*-]).{8,20}$");
if(uname.match(re)){
        DIMR = "Requirements MET";

    }else {
        DIMR = "Requirements NOT MET";


    }
```

Comment: ah! I'm discussing that in javascript chat. Simplified http://jsfiddle.net/j5sxkun3/1/

Comment: What is : document.getElementById("pword1") ? Paste some HTML please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly escape a string when using `new RegExp` constructor.

Since you don't have any variables inside your pattern try

```
var str1 = "AAbb123.";
var str2 = "ell";
var re = /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[\\\+\=\.\[\]_£|\`¬':\;\~{}<>()#?!\@$\%^&*-]).{8,20}$/; 
if(str1.match(re)){
   alert("matched")
   }
       else {
       alert("doesnt match")
       }
```

Comment: A regex literal is indeed more appropriate for this task. A point for you!

Answer (score 1):

Escaping only few characters present inside the character class would be enough. When using `"` as regex delimiter, you need to escape the backslash in your regex one more time.

```
var re = new RegExp("^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[\\\\+=.\\[\\]_£|`¬':;~{}<>()#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,20}$");
```

special characters like `+`, `.`, `*` inside a character class would must match a literal `+` or `.` or `*`, so you don't need to escape it. To match a literal `\`, you need to escape that `\` exactly three times.